# Как настроить приложение MVC для работы через HTTPS соединение?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, https, config

Доброго времени суток.

Суть вопроса изложена в заголовке. Нужно ли вручную создавать сертификат и подкручивать его к IIS? Или достаточно просто прописать что-то в файле **Web.config**??? Или нужно перед каждым методом всех контроллеров указывать **[RequireHttps]**??? Если есть нормальная документация, ткните носом, пожалуйста, потому что я ничего особо дельного не нашла...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, сертификат нужно подкрутить в IIS, инструкция и бесплатный сертфикат на год могут быть найдены, например, [тут](https://www.startssl.com/?lang=ru).

Также, в IIS для работы по HTTPS MVC сайта требуется правильно указать биндинг к https:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы не собираетесь использовать для сайта защищённый и обычный HTTP одновременно, то никаких атрибутов указывать не требуется, как и править Web.config - IIS не будет отзываться на обычные HTTP запросы.

Answer (score 3):

Если создать сертификат для сервера самостоятельно (self signed certificate), то многие браузеры будут выдавать пользователю предупреждающее сообщение.

Чтобы такого предупреждения не было, нужно заказать/купить SSL-сертификат у подтвержденных центров сертификации. Сделать это можно, например, у регистраторов доменов или хостинг провайдеров.

Как настроить ssl-сертификат в IIS можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis).

Как сделать ssl-сертификат самому в IIS [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127.aspx).

Веб-приложение будет работать без каких-либо правок в web.config.

Атрибут RequireHttps требует вызывать отмеченный методы (Action) по HTTPS.

Comment: Процедура создания самоподписанного сертификата под Windows мне знакома, его потом можно поместить в доверенные корневые, и тогда браузеры начнут работать в нормальном режиме. Я надеялась, что есть путь проще, чем прикручивать сертификат к IIS. Значит, RequireHttps всего лишь говорит приложению, что нужно использовать https, но если оно не настроено, ничего не получится. А как настроить использование https по умолчанию для всех action?

Comment: RequireHttps можно добавлять к контроллеру. Можно так GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); А еще вариант настроить WebSite в IIS с атрибутом всегда использовать SSL.

Comment: поняла, спасибо!)